# Typecheck fail on wrapped component of a React HOC

Tags: typescript

component parameter in the React HOC function fail typecheck with this code:

```
import * as React from 'react';

interface FooProps {
  foo: string;
  bar: string;
}

function withProps<P extends FooProps>(
  Comp: React.ComponentType<P>
) {
  return class extends React.Component {
    render() {
      return <Comp foo="foo" bar="bar"/>  // "Comp" fail typecheck
    }
  }
}
```

I was expecting that `P extends FooProps` constraint is enough but is not.

I got this error:

```
Type '{ foo: string; bar: string; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & P & { children?: ReactNode; }'.
  Property 'foo' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & P & { children?: ReactNode; }'.
```

Visual Studio Code intellisense successful detect `foo` and `bar` props as `FooProps.foo` and `FooProps.bar` respectively but fail on `Comp`

Why this not work as espected?

I think I don't get how generic functions infer generic variable types.

NOTE: Using `Comp: React.ComponentType<FooProps>` works OK.

Answer (score 0):

Ok.

Typescript complaint due I only pick declared props on Props, `foo` and `bar`, but `extends` imply that type of `P` could have more props.

This is solved passing the rest(unknown props) from P with `...this.props`. Something like this:

```
import * as React from 'react';

interface FooProps {
  foo: string;
  bar: string;
}

function withProps<P extends FooProps>(
  Comp: React.ComponentType<P>
) {
  return class extends React.Component<P> {
    render() {
      return <Comp {...this.props} foo="foo" bar="bar" />
    }
  }
}
```

See `...this.props` in `<Comp .../>`  and how P props needed to be passed to HOC component as well.

Answer (score 0):

Re-answer my self again.

The answer is not good because `...this.props` "shadow" required props and it`s types. Now I can put this and typecheck not FAIL and should.

```
    render() {
      return <Comp {...this.props} foo1="foo" bar={8} /> // Should FAIL typecheck
    }
```

Then, the above answer is wrong.

Comment: You have to spread the props using a cast since the types get erased due to a bug since TypeScript 3.2. Just write `{...this.props as P}` assuming `P` is the type of the props.

Comment: @Chistian still not work with type assertion `<Comp {...this.props as P} foo={9} bar="bar" />`.  Where is the typescript 3.2 issue?

Comment: Well I got the typescript URL issue but `...this.props as P` not work :-)

Answer (score 0):

The correct answer is that my initial code is right:

```
import * as React from 'react';

interface FooProps {
  foo: string;
  bar: string;
}

function withProps<P extends FooProps>(
  Comp: React.ComponentType<P>
) {
  return class extends React.Component {
    render() {
      return <Comp foo="foo" bar="bar"/>  // "Comp" typecheck OK
    }
  }
}
```

The problem is a bug on TS from 3.1.6 to 3.3-RC: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/28938

Going back to `3.1.4` works like expected.

**NOTE: Is working with Typescript `3.3.0-dev.20190117`